# Cannot read property 'propHooks' of undefined jQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, coloranimation

I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'propHooks' of undefined
```

When using [color animation](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the page

http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

And look out for the following:

**For jQuery 1.8 and later...**

and

**For jQuery 1.7 and earlier...**

Chances are you just need to upgrade your jQuery, or downgrade your animation plugin.